# Mongodb findAndModify keep replacing my document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hey guys i'm trying to perform findAndModify but it keep replacing new document and overwrite the old one this is what i have so far

```
posts.findAndModify({'permalink': data.permalink},{ update: {$inc: { 'votes.up': 1 }},'$addToSet': {'votes.voted_id': data._id} },{ new: true },{upsert:true}, function(err, post) {
            "use strict";
            if (err) return callback(err, null);
            callback(err, post);
   });
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Right now, it's modifying existing documents based on your query. The `upsert` and `new` options need to be passed as a single option object: `{ new: true, upsert: true }`

Comment: @WiredPrairie hi thanks for your reply, i'm trying to update the 'votes.up' by increase 1 and $addToSet data._id to 'votes.voted_id' after that i need the updated document return

Comment: Did you try merging the options as I suggested? It's a bit hard to follow all of the braces as you didn't format the code for the Stack overflow code block width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the shell parameter conventions for your node.js call, so your parameters are incorrect.

It should be reformatted into separate parameters like this instead:

```
posts.findAndModify(
    {'permalink': data.permalink},
    null,
    {$inc: {'votes.up': 1},
     '$addToSet': {'votes.voted_id': data._id}},
    {new: true,
     upsert: true},
    function(err, post) {
        "use strict";
        if (err) return callback(err, null);
        callback(err, post);
   });
```

Docs [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#find-and-modify).